# Error: Cannot find module 'pretty-bytes'

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, gulp, yeoman, yeoman-generator-angular

I am getting Error: Cannot find module 'pretty-bytes' error on my mac machine when I do yo gulp-angular.

Not able to run gulp serve after getting this error

Answer (score 0):

When you have a `Error: Cannot find module` it means that you're trying to require a package that is not installed yet.

Open a terminal then `cd`  in your project root. When you're in your projet root you can install the module by executing `npm install pretty-bytes`.

You should also consider adding it to your `package.json` file either in the `dependencies` or the `devDependencies`.